# Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack

After updating my android studio from 3.3 to 3.4 I am now getting this error.

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Notice that My project was fine before upgrading Android Studio.

To fix this I tried the following:
1. Adding the two dependencies

```
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0'
```

But the problem is still there.

2. Invalidate cache and restart.
3. Clean and rebuild

All of them didn't work.

The dependencies which are seemed not to be resolved are listed here in [Google's Maven Repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) but android studio could not resolve them. How can I fix this, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is your distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties?

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

Comment: then use below dependencies:
implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc02'

Comment: Thanks for asking me my distributionUrl. I just upgraded it yesterday from gradle-4.10.1 to gradle-5.1.1. After reverting it now my project sync successiful

Comment: Great :) but you can also try using 5.1.1 with above suggested urls by me and let me know if its working or not

Comment: I tried it yesterday and It didnt work

Comment: And now It works even if I dont have the two dependencies.

Comment: it is not working in my case can you please suggest some alternate methods???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by reverting distributionUrl in **gradle-wrapper.properties**

from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

back to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

And also reverting gradle dependency in **build.gradle**
from

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

back to

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

This seems like temporary solution though.

Comment: I can't understand why we have to downgrade our version of Gradle and these bugs are not going to fix

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad do you face this problem with the latest version? If not upgrade to latest I think it is fixed there.