# Jetpack version of android.support

Tags: android, kotlin, dependencies, deprecated

I am a noob at Kotlin/android and I am trying to make a sidebar(also called navigation drawer). I tried to follow this tutorial:
https://medium.com/quick-code/android-navigation-drawer-e80f7fc2594f

and I soon had to import `com.android.support:design`. I searched up the name of the library to get the latest version but found out the it was deprecated. It had been replaced with Jetpack. I tried finding it but couldn't find the `android.support` Jetpack alternative anywhere. What is it? If there isn't, how do you create a navigation drawer with modern dependencies? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidX support libraries are split in more fine-grained pieces. Instead of "design", look for the class itself on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com) to locate where it can be found.

In this case, the library you need is [`androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/drawerlayout).

Comment: In the link I gave you, they tell you to paste some code into the activity_main.xml file. When I do that after importing the library, it still gives me red lines on the <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> tag.

Comment: AndroidX `DrawerLayout` is in another package. `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`

Comment: When I add it, it gives me this error: `Failed to resolve: androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout:1.1.0:`

Comment: That's the gradle dependency you're configuring? That's `androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.0`. `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout` is the class name you use in XML layouts and code.

Comment: Oh... Okay. I will try it out and mark your answer as correct. I can't do it right now since I am in virtual school. Thanks for the noob help!

Answer (score 1):

`Support design` has been deprecated. You need `Material Components`.
In your app level `build.gradle` file add
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`.
Read more about it here https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

**Note :** Check for the current version

Comment: it gives me the error: `Failed to resolve: androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout:1.1.0:`

Comment: Is your project using ```Androidx dependencies``` ?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: May be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807789/could-not-resolve-androidx-drawerlayoutdrawerlayout1-0-0